# Replacing each match with a different word

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression like this:

```
findthe = re.compile(r" the ")
replacement = ["firstthe", "secondthe"]
sentence = "This is the first sentence in the whole universe!"
```

What I am trying to do is to replace each occurrence with an associated replacement word from a list so that the end sentence would look like this:

```
>>> print sentence
This is firstthe first sentence in secondthe whole universe
```

I tried using `re.sub` inside a for loop enumerating over replacement but it looks like `re.sub` returns all occurrences. Can someone tell me how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is not required to use regEx than you can try to use the following code:

```
replacement = ["firstthe", "secondthe"]
sentence = "This is the first sentence in the whole universe!"

words = sentence.split()

counter = 0
for i,word in enumerate(words):
    if word == 'the':
        words[i] = replacement[counter]
        counter += 1

sentence = ' '.join(words)
```

Or something like this will work too:

```
import re
findthe = re.compile(r"\b(the)\b")
print re.sub(findthe, replacement[1],re.sub(findthe, replacement[0],sentence, 1), 1)
```

And at least:

```
re.sub(findthe, lambda matchObj: replacement.pop(0),sentence)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the replacement logic is a little more complex for me. What I have provided is a test case. In my case, there could be 10-20 `the`'s. It can still be done using your method but I'm looking for a more concise approach. But +1 for your help.

Comment: Thank you - check the last one solution.

Answer (score 5):

Artsiom's last answer is destructive of `replacement` variable. Here's a way to do it without emptying `replacement`

```
re.sub(findthe, lambda m, r=iter(replacement): next(r), sentence)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback function as the replace parameter, see how at:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub

Then use some counter and replace depending on the counter value.

Comment: Thank You. I will play around with it now and get back.